# Xamarin Forms - Create Entry or Picker dynamically based on a property and bind it to a ObservableCollection object

Tags: xamarin.forms, view, binding, dynamic-forms

I have a xamarin forms application that receives data from the database. The database gives "Car" data back. Those objects all have a couple of properties. On of those properties decides what kind of view should be shown on the screen. So a car could have a property named "TypeOfView" with a value "Entry" or "Picker" etc..

The problem is a follows: How can I dynamically create views based on that property and how can that be bind to objects in a list in the viewmodel?

// This is the codebehind where UI controls get created

```
        BindingContext = DependencyInjectionService.Get<CheckListEditViewModel>();

        var stack = new StackLayout()
        {
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical,
            Padding = 5
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < (BindingContext as CheckListEditViewModel).CheckListItems.Count; i++)
        {
            var item = (BindingContext as CheckListEditViewModel).CheckListItems[i];

            var description = new Label()
            {
                Text = item.Description
            };
            stack.Children.Add(description);

            if ((item.ChecklistItemType == Domain.ChecklistItemType.Number))
            {
                     var numerEntry = new Entry();
                numerEntry.Keyboard = Keyboard.Numeric;
                numerEntry.TextChanged += MyMethod;

                numerEntry.SetBinding(Entry.TextProperty, new Binding(mode: BindingMode.TwoWay, path: "Value", source: item));
                stack.Children.Add(numerEntry);

                // this is to test if the binding worked
                var testLabelBindingTesting = new Label();
                testLabelBindingTesting.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding(mode: BindingMode.TwoWay, path: "Value", source: item));
                stack.Children.Add(testLabelBindingTesting);
            }
            else if ((item.ChecklistItemType == Domain.ChecklistItemType.Email))
            {
                var numerEntry = new Entry();
                numerEntry.Keyboard = Keyboard.Email;
                stack.Children.Add(numerEntry);
            }
        }

        Content = stack;
```

// The list is in the viewmodel class:

```
        public ObservableCollection<ChecklistItem> CheckListItems { get; set; }
```

Comment: As you can see, the codebehind has the code which iterates over a observablecollection. when iterating over each element, it takes a property to decide what UI component should be created. Then, it binds to a property from an element. The UI now shows the created components and uses the binding to set the values. But now I want to fill some text in the entry, the list should notify the UI so that other components can react to it.

Comment: You can add a textchanged event to the Entry. Entry.TextChanged += EntryTextChanged;  This line of code will tell you when the user inputs data.

Comment: Is it shown as a List? You can use DataTemplateSelector. @MYil

Comment: How do you choose the property to create the view, using picker? What does "bind to objects in a list in the viewmodel" mean?